# A pod with a web application that is in GKE, can have a subdomain appspot.com?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

A pod with a web application that is in GKE, can have a subdomain appspot.com ?, just like in GAE.

I have a cluster in GKE, and within this I have some services, including a web application that uses a ngnix ingress. Currently I do not want to acquire a paid domain, but I would like to expose my web application in a subdomain appspot.com, is this possible?

I have read that the applications found in GAE are automatically associated with a subdomain of appspot.com, but is it possible to expose applications in GKE?

Comment: If you create a load balancer for an application, you can use `IP.ADD.RE.SS.xip.io` as a domain name for testing purposes.

Comment: AhmetB, thanks.. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. Domain appspot.com is specific for GAE and some other fully managed GCloud services but not for GKE. In GKE you have to do everything yourself - create domain, expose your app on load balancer, create record and all that stuff. But domains are so cheap, why not buy one?

Comment: Thanks, I've been thinking to buy a domain after to make some tests, So I'll first try xip.io.